# how to test for inserts in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have an rspec test of a method that inserts or returns the first record if a record with given attributes doesn't exist. It looks like this

```
context "user doesn't exist" do
  subject { User.find_or_create(name: "Jonh", login: "john") }

  it { should be_an_instance_of(User) }

  //and here I want to test that new user was inserted into database...

end
```

but I can't figure out how to use `expect to change` in this.

Comment: why do you want to test that? usually you should only create it?

Comment: I want to check if my code creates new record when it should. Why wouldn't I want to test that?

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually test for this is by looking for the count of those objects to change:

```
it "creates a new user object" do
  expect {
    User.find_or_create(name: "John", login: "john")
  }.to change{User.count}.by(1)
end
```

Admittedly, it doesn't fit that well with the `subject` pattern you've started with, but it's a necessary evil when you're testing that a certain method causes a change in the state of the system, rather than testing that objects have certain properties.